# Linked List in C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I was searching for a implementation of a Linked List with the same power as a native `List`.

I wanted  functionality closer to a `List`. The `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList` misses some methods I'm used to work with, like `Add` `Sort` or access by index `mylist[0]`

I didn't find one so I made one of my own:

- I added the same constructors as `List`
- I used a merge sort which should be the most performant for this case
- I added `IEnumberable` to be able to use the power of Linq
- I added all native methods of a `List`

I'm searching for mistakes, performance improvements or missing functionality.

Note: This is not about a circular or doubly linked list; it's just about a singly linked list.

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T data;
    public Node<T> next;
}

public class MyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    private Node<T> _headNode;
    private int _count;
    public int Count { get { { return _count; } } }

    private IEnumerable<Node<T>> Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            Node<T> node = _headNode;
            while (node != null)
            {
                yield return node;
                node = node.next;
            }
        }
    }

    private Node<T> Pop()
    {
        Node<T> tResult = null;
        if (_headNode != null)
        {
            tResult = _headNode;
            _headNode = _headNode.next;
            _count--;
        }
        return tResult;
    }

    private void Push(Node<T> item)
    {
        item.next = _headNode;
        _headNode = item;
        _count++;
    }

    private Node<T> NodeAt(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index + 1 > _count)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index");
        }
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (Node<T> item in Nodes)
        {
            if (counter == index)
            {
                return item;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public MyLinkedList()
    {
        _headNode = null;
        _count = 0;
    }

    public MyLinkedList(IEnumerable<T> Items)
    {
        foreach (T item in Items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void ForEach(Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (Node<T> item in Nodes)
        {
            action(item.data);
        }
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> Items)
    {
        foreach (T item in Items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void AddRange(params T[] Items)
    {
        foreach (T item in Items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return NodeAt(index).data; }
        set { NodeAt(index).data = value; }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Node<T> item in Nodes)
        {
            yield return item.data;
        }
    }

    public bool Exists(T value)
    {
        foreach (Node<T> item in Nodes)
        {
            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, item.data) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _headNode = null;
        _count = 0;
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        if (_headNode != null)
        {
            Random rRand = new Random();
            T[] aResult = new T[_count];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (Node<T> nItem in Nodes)
            {
                int j = rRand.Next(i + 1);
                if (i != j)
                {
                    aResult[i] = aResult[j];
                }
                aResult[j] = nItem.data;
                i++;
            }
            this.Clear();
            this.AddRange(aResult);
        }
    }

    public void Sort()
    {
        _headNode = MergeSortSub(_headNode);
    }

    private Node<T> MergeSortSub(Node<T> nHead)
    {
        if (nHead == null || nHead.next == null) { return nHead; }
        Node<T> nSeeker = nHead;
        Node<T> nMiddle = nSeeker;
        while (nSeeker.next != null && nSeeker.next.next != null)
        {
            nMiddle = nMiddle.next;
            nSeeker = nSeeker.next.next;
        }
        Node<T> sHalf = nMiddle.next;
        nMiddle.next = null;
        Node<T> nFirst = MergeSortSub(nHead);
        Node<T> nSecond = MergeSortSub(sHalf);
        Node<T> nResult = new Node<T>();
        Node<T> nCurrent = nResult;
        while (nFirst != null && nSecond != null)
        {
            IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
            if (comparer.Compare(nFirst.data, nSecond.data) < 1)
            {
                nCurrent.next = nFirst;
                nFirst = nFirst.next;
            }
            else
            {
                nCurrent.next = nSecond;
                nSecond = nSecond.next;
            }
            nCurrent = nCurrent.next;
        }
        nCurrent.next = (nFirst == null) ? nSecond : nFirst;
        return nResult.next;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Node<T> NewNode = new Node<T>() { data = item, next = _headNode };
        _headNode = NewNode;
        _count++;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(T Value)
    {
        int IndexCount = 0;
        foreach (Node<T> item in Nodes)
        {
            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item.data, Value) == 0)
            {
                yield return IndexCount;
            }
            IndexCount++;
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T Value)
    {
        IEnumerator<int> eN = AllIndexesOf(Value).GetEnumerator();
        if (eN.MoveNext())
        {
            return eN.Current;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int LastIndexOf(T Value)
    {
        IEnumerator<int> eN = AllIndexesOf(Value).GetEnumerator();
        int Result = -1;
        while (eN.MoveNext())
        {
            Result = eN.Current;
        }
        return Result;
    }

    public void RemoveAll(Func<T, bool> match)
    {
        while (_headNode != null && match(_headNode.data)) //  head node
        {
            _headNode = _headNode.next;
            _count--;
        }
        if (_headNode != null)
        {
            Node<T> nTemp = _headNode;
            while (nTemp.next != null)// other nodes
            {
                if (match(nTemp.next.data))
                {
                    nTemp.next = nTemp.next.next;
                    _count--;
                }
                else
                {
                    nTemp = nTemp.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Predicate<T> match)
    {
        foreach (Node<T> item in Nodes)
        {
            if (match(item.data))
            {
                yield return item.data;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Distinct()
    {
        HashSet<T> uniques = new HashSet<T>();
        Node<T> nTemp = _headNode;
        if (nTemp != null)
        {
            uniques.Add(_headNode.data);
            while (nTemp.next != null)
            {
                if (!uniques.Add(nTemp.next.data))
                {
                    nTemp.next = nTemp.next.next;
                    _count--;
                }
                else
                {
                    nTemp = nTemp.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Reverse()
    {
        Node<T> nCurrent = _headNode;
        Node<T> nBack = null;
        while (nCurrent != null)
        {
            Node<T> nTemp = nCurrent.next;
            nCurrent.next = nBack;
            nBack = nCurrent;
            nCurrent = nTemp;
        }
        _headNode = nBack;
    }

    public void RemoveFirst()
    {

        if (_headNode != null)
        {
            _headNode = _headNode.next;
            _count--;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveLast()
    {
        if (_headNode != null)
        {
            if (_headNode.next == null)
            {
                _headNode = null;
            }
            else
            {
                NodeAt(Count - 2).next = null;
            }
            _count--;
        }
    }

    public void AddLast(T item)
    {
        Node<T> NewNode = new Node<T>() { data = item, next = null };
        if (_headNode == null)
        {
            _headNode = NewNode;
        }
        else
        {
            NodeAt(Count - 1).next = NewNode;
        }
        _count++;
    }

    public void Insert(T item, int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index + 1 > _count)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index");
        }

        Node<T> NewNode = new Node<T>() { data = item, next = null };
        if (index == 0)
        {
            NewNode.next = _headNode;
            _headNode = NewNode;
        }
        else
        {
            NewNode.next = NodeAt(index - 1).next;
            NodeAt(index - 1).next = NewNode;
        }
        _count++;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index + 1 > _count)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index");
        }

        if (index == 0)
        {
            _headNode = _headNode.next;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> temp = NodeAt(index - 1);
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
        }
        _count--;
    }

    public void RemoveRange(int index, int count)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index + count > _count)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index");
        }
        if (index == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                _headNode = _headNode.next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> nStart = NodeAt(index - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                nStart.next = nStart.next == null ? null : nStart.next.next;
            }
        }
        _count -= count;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can probably add extension functions for some of those desired methods.  Generally developers avoid re-implementing a built-in .net feature, unless there is a justifiable reason, which I don't want to be judgy, but you can probably avoid reimplementation in your case.

Comment: Out of interest, `List` will be faster than both the built in `LinkedList` and the one you're making. Linked lists are naturally slower in modern computers because of issues with caching and memory locality. And a doubly linked list is still a linked list, what you're talking about is a singly linked list, many people take 'linked list' on its own to refer to doubly linked list because they're more common and more useful.

Comment: Tolani Jaiye-Tikolo's answer made me wonder: why treat a linked list as a 'normal' list without taking advantage of its benefits? Doesn't that give you the worst of both worlds? Poor indexing performance *and* poor insertion performance?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I think there is no reason to use a Linked List productive. The performance is worse in almost every case - I've benchmaked a lot and the only method that's faster compared to a List: inserting items always at the first possition :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just a few quick remarks:

- Creating a linked list from another enumerable stores items in *reverse* order. That's probably not what most people would expect. Note that `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList` does preserve the original order.
- A similar case can be made for `Add`: it adds items to the front. People familiar with `List<T>` would expect it to add at the end. Note that `LinkedList` explicitly uses `AddFirst` and `AddLast`, likely to prevent such confusion. Granted, not all collections are ordered, but if you do want to stick to this behavior, then at least document it.
- Implement `ICollection(<T>)` and `IList(<T>)` while you're at it. You already implemented most of their functionality anyway (sometimes with different method names, or methods with different argument order).
- Keeping track of the tail node allows you to improve the performance of adding items at the end (at the expense of making removing and inserting nodes a bit more complicated).
- There are several methods that don't really need to be member methods, such as `Find`, `Distinct` and `Reverse`. Linq already provides extension methods for these (using mostly the same names, except that `Find` is called `Where`).
- The same can be said for `ForEach`: it can easily be implemented as an extension method, which would make it available for everything that implements `IEnumerable(<T>)`. Or you could just use `foreach`.
- Some methods appear to be unused, such as `Pop` and `Push`.

Comment: Find and Distinct are going to behave similar to the Linq version, but "Reverse()" is actually reversing the list itself, and it avoids the temporary storage that a generic "Reverse()" method requires over an IEnumerable<>

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to quickly point to one *huge* problem with the current implementation.

Your linked list uses extensively the `NodeAt` method which is *O(n)*. The `AddLast` in the original implementation is however *O(1)*. This could be a real bottle neck.

---

In a [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138142/linked-list-in-c#comment258080_138142) you say that:

> The System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList misses some methods i'm used to
>   work with, like Add Sort or access by index mylist[0]

- The LinkeList's `Add` method is `AddLast`
- You can sort the items with `OrderBy`
- You can access elements by index with `ElementAt` (and it would be as fast or rather as slow as your implementation)

For example:

```
var foo = new LinkedList<string>(new[] { "z", "b", "a", "c" });
var fooSorted = new LinkedList<string>(foo.OrderBy(x => x));
var nthFoo = foo.ElementAt(2);
```

The sorting and returning a new linked list could be an extension too.

Comment: O(1) isn't possible with a Linked List. I decided knowingly not to implement a circular or doulby linked list.

Comment: @fubo [LinkedList<T>.AddLast Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132177(v=vs.110).aspx) _This method is an O(1) operation._ like a few others that make the linked list so useful and fast.

Comment: @fubo Why? `LinkedList<T>` is implemented as a circular doubly linked list, which allows operations on the last node to be O(1).

Comment: @Random832 because this is about the heck of implementing a basic Linked List. I know about performance issues compared to a `List`and I know my Linked List is slower in almost every case.

Answer (score 13):

- Naming: local variables should be named using `camelCase`. `NewNode` => `newNode`.
- Some of the methods can be shortened by using LINQ. For example:

  ```
  public bool Exists(T value)
  {
      return Nodes.Any(node => Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, node.data) == 0);
  }
  ```

  Also, if your goal is to mimic `IList<T>` API then you might as well use the same method names: `Contains` instead of `Exists`.
- If you are creating a replacement for default `LinkedList` I would expect it to at least implement the same interfaces:

  > ```
  >   LinkedList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
  >   IEnumerable, ICollection, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, ISerializable, 
  >   IDeserializationCallback
  > ```

  You might also want to implement `IList<T>`. Your linked list also lacks some of the most basic functions, such as adding new elements to the back.
- All things considered, I don't think your class is very useful. If you need to access items by index often, then you should use regular `List<T>`, period. Regular list is not *that* slow when it comes to adding items, but it is *a lot* faster, when it comes to accessing items by index. If you need to get item by index once in while though, you should just create an extension method for regular linked list:

  ```
  public static T ElementAt<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, int index)
  {
      //throw "index out of range" exceptions, if needed
      return list.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();
  }
  ```

  And be done with it.
  **EDIT:** oh, mr. t3chb0t is right. I completely forgot, that LINQ already has `ElementAt` method. So you don't even have to implement it yourself. Even better.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to what other reviewers have identified.

- Amend your **constructor**: you should only trying adding items from a collection once the collection is not null.E,g doing the below will throw a `NullReferenceException`

```html
    MyLinkedList<string> myLinkedList = new MyLinkedList<string>(null);
    Console.WriteLine(myLinkedList.Count);
```

> Rather you should be throwing `ArgumentNullException`. For instance

```
 public MyLinkedList(IEnumerable<T> Items)
        {
            if (Items == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Items));
            }
            foreach (T item in Items)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
        }
```

- There is so much confusion in your implementation e.g `Find` . From my perspective `Find` should be returning a `Node` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` hence it should be used in the `NodeAt` method. In general, the C# definition for `Find` identifies based on a parameter called `value` which is the `data` in your `Node` class e.g

```html
 public LinkedListNode<T> Find(T value)
        {
            // finds node and returns node
            return null;
        }
```

> Since there is no dependency on your `Find` method, it can be extended to find a node based on `indexing`. Below is a snippet

```
   private Node<T> NodeAt(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index + 1 > _count)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index");
            }
           Node<T> foundNode = Nodes.Find(index);
           // return foundNode

            return null;
        }

  public Node<T> Find(T item)
        {
            Node<T> node = _headNode;
            while (node != _headNode)
            {
                // iteratively  assign node to the next item and compare the data
            }
            return null;
        }
```

- When you've two methods doing the same thing you should be worried - **DRY** . This has happened with the two `AddRange` methods. An `Array` by default has a fixed size and `params` allows you to dynamic add a variable number of items. This is equal to using an `ArrayList` in C#. If I may remind you again `ArrayList` implements the `IEnumerable` interface  which makes the second method pretty redundant.

Comment: `Find` should not return a node - nodes are an internal implementation detail, and returning one would allow a caller to mess with it. Taking a predicate and returning a value is consistent with other `Find` methods. The only issue is that it's called `Find` instead of `FindAll`.

Comment: you maybe right.. In the context of a LinkedList implemetation the Find does return a Node. Taking a predicate is also a good approach to this. It willl also be helpful if OP used a good naming Convention FindAll instead of Find.

Comment: You're right, `LinkedList<T>.Find` returns a node (I was only looking at `List<T>.Find` and `Array.Find`). But `LinkedList<T>` also offers methods that accept nodes as arguments, so they're part of the public 'interface', which is not the case with the OP's code. Exposing and using nodes like that looks like a better design - it forces you to take the characteristics of a linked list into account (e.g. no cheap random access).

Answer (score 6):

Before I add additional points I'd like to emphasise some of the things others have brought up. Particularly that wanting to index a linked list is never a good idea, and that all local variables and parameters should use camel case instead of pascal case.

- There is no need to use the bare enumerator in `IndexOf` and
  `LastIndexOf`, you should use a `foreach` instead. e.g

  ```
  public int IndexOf(T Value)
  {
      foreach (var n in AllIndexesOf(Value).GetEnumerator())
      {
          return n;
      }
      return -1;
  }
  ```
- `Node` deserves its own constructor, not just a default one. Also its
  fields should not be public because it means people using your class
  can start fiddling with the internals of the list by assigning to the
  node's fields. Instead you should hide them to everything but your
  `LinkedList` and give `Node<T>` some `public` `get`-only properties.
  The best ways to hide the fields from outside code would probably be
  to make them `internal` instead of `public`.
- Stylistically `Nodes` should be a method instead of a property
  because properties aren't really meant to be used like that.
- People might try to disagree with me here, but the preferred plural
  of index in a technical setting (e.g. computer science) is indices.
  `AllIndexesOf` should be `AllIndicesOf`, and even then the `All` part
  is debatable since it's heavily implied. If I am asking for the
  indices of something I'd be pretty annoyed if some got left out
  unless I had specified a reason to leave them out.
- A lot of your methods look like they should be extension methods such
  as `Shuffle` and `Find(Predicate<T> match)`. The Enumerable
  extensions in Linq actually provide `Find` for you, except it's
  called
  [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx).
- The method `RemoveAll` should ideally be called `RemoveWhere` given
  its predicate-based nature. Also the fact it uses a `Func<T, bool>`
  instead of a `Predicate<T>` find is an issue. When it comes to
  `Predicate<T>` and `Func<T, bool>` you should ideally choose one and
  stick to it.
- I'm not entirely sure how good your shuffle algorithm is, but I'm
  willing to bet it's not as good as it could be. I suggest using an
  implementation of the [Fisher-Yates
  Shuffle](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) to
  ensure a good level of randomness.
- Lastly, `AddRange(params T[] Items)` could be rerouted to use
  `AddRange(IEnumerable<T> Items)` by using a cast.